# how to create CLSID for a dll using regasm.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

how can we create CLSID for  DLL using regasm.exe

Actaully i want to use a windows application on web, i found an article on that, im posting the link below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14276/Using-Windows-Application-on-web

In the above article im facing issue near the 10th step where it states that:: "Now by using the "regasm.exe" create and place the CLSID of your dll in the registry the exe file which is in the location "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\ "."

im not sure how to create the CLSID for the dll?

Comment: You can create one by using the command line utility `uuidgen.exe`

Comment: command line utility means visual studio command prompt, can u be little more clear pls?

Answer (score 1):

A CLSID identifies a COM class object, not a DLL.

When you register your assembly using regasm, a CLSID will be registered for each ComVisible class in your assembly.

You can specify the CLSID you want by placing a `Guid` attribute on a class:

```
[GuidAttribute("12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789abc")]
public sealed class MyComVisibleClass ...
```

or if you don't use this attribute it will be generated automatically.

If it's generated automatically, you can inspect the type library generated by regasm using "OLE Viewer" or similar.

Comment: how can i register my assembly using regasm.exe?

Answer (score 0):

By calling

```
regasm.exe /codebase /tlb whatever.dll
```

depending on your needs, /codebase or /tlb might not be needed (i.e. you can also try just `regasm.exe whatever.dll`).

Comment: my need is just to create the CLSID and get its value, directly should i place it in command prompt i.e,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>regasm.exe/myapp.dll....?

Comment: when i tried C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>regasm.exe\myapp.dll, im getting the error as the directory name is invalid?

Comment: no, the referenced article is not very good, and it uses confusing terminology. You need to register the dll (and part of registration is writing CLSID into registry, among other things, but you don't do it yourself) and it is done by executing `regasm` as I wrote. I am confident that you are able to specify correct dll.  If you need the CLSID, you can open the generated tlb file (therefore `/tlb` switch) in OLE/COM Viewer Tool (part of Visual Studio) and read it from there.

Comment: what does `regasm.exe\myapp.dll` look like to you? Is it surprising that you have that error? Did you take a look at what I wrote?

Comment: sorry for my lameness, im not technically that sound....i opened microsovt visual studio 2010/microsoft windows sdk tools/OLE-COM object viewer, im not able to find tlb switch there?...actually do u mean type libraries?

Comment: I assume that, if you can use VS, you can also use a command line tool. I am not sure if I can write it clearer than `path\to\regasm.exe /codebase /tlb name_of_your.dll`

Answer (score 0):

A CLSID is a globally unique ID (=GUID). It has a fixed format (see the Answer from Joe) and is "random". You can create one with guidgen.exe. Many Editors and IDE's have functionality to create a GUID. With regasm you can register the GUID (=CLSID then) of your COM class object in windows.

Comment: so 1st i need to create one GUID(which means CLSID) and then i should register it using REGASM.EXE, am i right?